# What is the word for "trappy"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose a person has been accused of doing something wrong and a cunning policeman is questioning him. Suppose the police is asking questions in such a way that it is very likely that the accused person is likely to be found out if he, in fact, had done something wrong.

What can we say about the type of questions the policeman is asking. I am looking for an adjective like "*trappy*", if there were such a thing, meaning "*full of traps*". Are there any words like this?

**EDIT**- I would like to point out that please don't take my example as if the word could be used with Police procedure only. That was mere an example to let you understand the scenario. The word may describe conversation by anybody. Even one of my friends can also ask such questions of me if he/she has some doubts about me.

Comment: You might also call these questions _tricky_ or _trick questions_. The notion that they are trying to **trap** the suspect suggests the possibility of [_entrapment_](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/entrapment). Although the definition refers to tricking someone into committing a crime, I think it can be extended to tricking someone into incriminating himself by saying things that indicate guilt, including a false confession. However, I also like Jim's two suggestions plus _trenchant_.

Comment: @BillFranke - I believe yours is a much better word. Why don't you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

You could continue the *trap* metaphor with *trap-laden*.

Comment: Or trap-laden? Laden as a pa.p of 'to lade', meaning to load. I'm not sure 'laiden' exists as a pa.p.

Comment: @Mynamite Indeed, *laiden* is not a word.

Comment: @Théophile well, it is an attested variant, but yes, that was just a thinko.

Answer (score 2):

I would say he is asking *penetrating* or *pointed* questions.

> [***penetrating***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/penetrating) : *Keenly perceptive or understanding; acute*
>
> [***pointed***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pointed) : *cutting or incisive*

Or for a more poetic take on it:

His line of questioning laid out an impenetrable minefield for the guilty.

Answer (score 2):

Police *interrogation* techniques include the use of [loaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question) and [suggestive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suggestive_question#Interrogators_and_police) questions.

> Unethical or unskilled police officers can use suggestive questioning in interrogation rooms. Such interrogators use different kinds of techniques and questions in order to get people to confess. They use response framing when getting people to falsely confess. This is when they purposely limit certain answers and suggest others. For example, they would ask someone if they were at the house at 1, 2, or 3 o’clock, forcing them to think it had to have been one of those choices. It causes people to recall things from the prompt instead of their memories. Also, interrogators use stereotype induction, which is when they tell the witness only negative characteristics of the alleged perpetrator. Part of stereotype induction is the incriminating condition where everything the witness says is labeled as bad. The detective would slightly shake his head or tell the witness to try again. This contrasts with another interrogating option of using a neutral interview technique, which includes both the bad and good aspects of the perpetrator.

Neither of these techniques is considered to be ethically sound for reasons similar to those provided by Bill Franke in the comments in respect to [entrapment](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/entrap).

In addition to Jim's *penetrating* and *pointed*, you could also use the word [probing](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/probe?q=probe) to describe the questions asked during an interrogation.

Comment: +1 for _loaded questions_. I was looking for that, but it totally eluded me.

Answer (score 1):

I think *pointed questions* and *loaded questions* are two excellent candidates, put forth by Jim and coleopterist, respectively.

I'd like to add one more to the list: *leading questions*. From NOAD:

> **leading question** (*n*.) a question that prompts or encourages the desired answer

*Leading questions* are sometimes considered to be an unfair interrogation technique. [One website](http://changingminds.org/techniques/questioning/questioning_traps.htm) mentions:

> Leading questions are those that nudge, push or shove the other person towards a particular answer and away from other answers. They are a very common form of bias.

Also, the difference between *leading questions* and *loaded questions* is discussed some on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading_question).

Answer (score 0):

I rather like the word "ensnaring" for something like that.

Comment: Could you please give some more detail as to why you think this is an appropriate word?